# Unexpected behaviour of printf function in c

Tags: c, printf

I recently encountered with an interview question. I did not understand the behaviour of `printf` function in this case

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() {
 int k = printf("String");
 printf("%d",k);
 }
```

Expected result : Compilation Error

Output : `String6`

Why is the output `String6`?

Comment: *Expected result : Compilation Error* - why is that? The code is perfectly valid (except that `main()` should be `main(void)`)

Comment: Which part of this do you not understand?

Comment: Why the output is String6

Answer (score 6):

Here is the prototype for `printf`:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

We can see that `printf` returns an `int`.

The [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) indicates that:

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
>          characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
>          strings).

---

You asked why the output is "String6". Well:

```
printf("String");
```

This first prints `String` but *does not* print a newline character. Since `String` is 6 characters, `printf` returns 6, which you store in `k`:

```
printf("%d",k);
```

This then prints `6` (on the same line).

---

Try running this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int bytes_printed = printf("%s\n", "String");
    //              7 =           1  +  6

    printf("printf returned: %d\n", bytes_printed);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
String
printf returned: 7
```

Comment: I was waiting for someone to mention the lack of newline character :)

Answer (score 4):

the `printf()` function returns the number of character it printed. Since you set `int k = printf("String");`, the print function is executing printing out "String" and setting `k` equal to 6 since "String" is 6 characters long, then your second call to `printf` prints the value of `k` which is 6, resulting in the console displaying "String6".

This is perfectly valid C syntax.